# Specify CLR namespace of auto-generated web service proxy class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, web-reference

When you add a Web Reference in an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio the web application's **root namespace** is always added.

So, if I add a web reference called **MyWebService** and the default namespace of the application is **MyApplication** the namespace of the generated proxy class will be: **MyApplication.MyWebService**.

However, I want to be able to specify which namespace to use for the generated class (to **skip the default namespace** and have the namespace be called simply MyWebService).

Is using **wsdl.exe** through the command line the only way of accomplishing this? I don't want to manually edit the generated class (since it can get re-generated).

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost seems using **wsdl.exe** is the only option?

I resorted to using a pre-build event for generating the proxy class. Put out a [post on how I did it here](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2010/9/change-namespace-for-web-service-proxy-class-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't figure anything else out either... Thanks for the link!